# How do you operate Delphi's macro recorder?

Tags: delphi, ide, macros

I am using Delphi 2009 and I noticed that there is a macro recorder below the code editor.
How do I use it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. click the record button
2. edit some text
3. click the stop button
4. click the run button

When you have gotten the concept change step 2 to your needs.

Comment: Ctr+R = Record, Ctrl+P = Playback, way faster that way. Examples of use: Surround block of text with 'ticks' (I use that maybe 1000 times a day, to surround an block of SQL with 'ticks' so I can assign it to some property)

Comment: i didn't get what you mean Mr Cosmin.I'd tried but it was just like a copy/paste. can you post your answer please?

Comment: The default shortcut for Record/Play are actually Ctrl+Shift+R/Ctrl+Shift+P.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try [GExperts' Macro Library expert](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/macrolibrary.html). It makes Delphi's macros much more useful to me.